# (Permission denied)] occurred while uploading a file to Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon S3. It works fine in my local, but I get the permission denied error while its deployed in Elastic Beanstalk.

My code:

```
public String uploadFileToS3BucketTemp(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, boolean enablePublicReadAccess, String filename, String path) 
    {
        LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        String currentDateTime = CommonFunctions.customDateFormatter(CommonFunctions.getCurrentDateTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date date = new Date();
        //Pattern for showing milliseconds in the time "SSS"
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        String str = sdf.format(date);
        
        String time = str.split("\\s")[1].split("\\.")[0];
        String currentTime =  time.replaceAll(":", "-");
        String fileName = filename+"-"+currentDateTime+"-"+ currentTime +".xls";
        String filePath = "";

        try {

            File file = new File(filePath+fileName);
        
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            baos.writeTo(fos);
            fos.close();
            
            InputStream is=new FileInputStream(file);
            
            
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, path+"/"+fileName, is, new ObjectMetadata()));
            
        } catch (IOException | AmazonServiceException ex) {
            logger.error("error [" + ex.getMessage() + "] occurred while uploading [" + fileName + "] ");
        }
        
        String url = signedUrl(path+"/"+fileName);
        
        return url;
    }
```

On checking the Server Logs it shows me the following error:

```
ERROR 25491 (Permission denied)] occurred while uploading
```

The bucket is not public. The ElasticBeantsalk has the IAM Role which has the permission AmazonS3FullAccess

Comment: Show the code where you create the `s3Client`

Comment: Can you show us the policy on the bucket. This can sometimes relate to ACLs

Answer (score 2):

"***I get the permission denied error while its deployed in Elastic Beanstalk***."

You can reference AWS examples that describe how to upload a given file from your desktop to an Amazon S3 bucket by using a web application written using Java. Because Java is used (a Spring BOOT app), you can use the AWS SDK for Java V2.

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

In this example, notice the app is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk. The Amazon S3 Service client is created like this:

```
 S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(region)
            .build();
```

On Elastic Beanstalk, you can set your creds to an IAM role that has Amazon S3 permissions by defining these variables:

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Now you can use the S3 Service client to place a file into an Amazon S3 bucket using this Java logic:

```
// Places an image into a S3 bucket.
public String putObject(byte[] data, String bucketName, String objectKey) {

    s3 = getClient();

    try {
        PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(bucketName)
                        .key(objectKey)
                        .build(),
                RequestBody.fromBytes(data));

        return response.eTag();

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct `AmazonS3` object in-order to call the API call `putObject()`.
There are two ways,

--> You can give credentials and construct `AmazonS3` (Not recommended for cloud deployment)

```
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key);
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion("ap-south-1")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .build();
```

--> You can give credentials via `AWS IAM` role. (Recommended)

```
    InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider provider = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true);
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(provider)
            .build();
```

You are suppose to give relevant permission for S3. (In this example, to invoke `putObject()`)

--> `putObject()` API call would be like below code block.

```
  public void upload(String thePath, String theFileName, Optional<Map<String, String>> theOptionalMetaData,
                       InputStream inputStream) {
        printLog("upload(): Executed with path - " + thePath + " and file name - " + theFileName);
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        theOptionalMetaData.ifPresent(map -> {
            //Loops through the optionalMetaData map adding all of the file information to the S3 objectMetaData.
            if (!map.isEmpty()) {
                map.forEach(objectMetadata::addUserMetadata);
            }
        });
        printLog("upload(): Done adding metadata");

        try {
            //Saves the file to Amazon S3 bucket
            amazonS3.putObject(thePath, theFileName, inputStream, objectMetadata);
        }
        catch (AmazonServiceException exception) {
            printLog("upload(): Exception upon uploading file");
            throw new IllegalStateException("Exception upon uploading file", exception);
        }
        printLog("upload(): File upload successful");
    }
```

Hope this post helps you to proceed, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check your ec2 instance profile and s3 bucket policy.

Make sure, instance profile has access to the S3 and S3 bucket policy is allowing objects put from the instance profile.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-s3-bucket-instance/